# Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections failed in Piecewise

Tags: manipulate

Having no idea of why there are intersections plotted.

```
g[x_] := 2 - x /; 1 <= x;
g[x_] := x /; x < 1;
Manipulate[
 Show[p1 = 
   Plot[Piecewise[{{g[t x + b], t x + b < 1}, {g[t x + b], 
       1 < t x + b}}], {x, -5, 5}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    PlotRange -> 5 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotStyle -> {Pink, Thick}],
  p2 = Plot[
    Piecewise[{{g[x], x < 0}, {g[x], 0 <= x < 1}, {g[x], 
       1 < x}}], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Thick}],
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large], 
    Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[p1, p2]}]],
 {{t, 2, "Times"}, -10, 10, 1}, {{b, 0, "Shift"}, -10, 10, 0.1}]
```

Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections suggest this has to be a list of rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I misunderstand your question. Actually your code doesn't work.

Here my working version

```
Manipulate[
plot = Plot[ {g[t x + b], g[x]}, {x, -5, 5},AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> 5 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},PlotStyle -> {{Pink, Thick},{Green, Thick}}];
Show[plot, Graphics[{PointSize[Large],Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plot]}]]
, {{t, 2, "Times"}, -10, 10, 1}, {{b, 0, "Shift"}, -10, 10,0.1}]
```

[image]

`g[x] and g[2x]` must have two intersections because both have a common point `{0,0}`